# How to keep "Pick an element from the page" active in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In Firefox, when I select `Pick an element from the page` from the `Inspect Element` menu and then I click on a page element, the `Pick an element from the page` button becomes inactive so, if I want to pick a different element, I have to click on it again.

How do I keep it active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Select_an_element):

> Starting in Firefox 52, if you <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click the element, then it is selected but the picker stays active. This lets you see the rules for the element in the CSS pane, but conveniently select another element in the page.